# zlib error webkit

Tags: zlib

I downloaded the WebKit source code and I am building the source code on ubuntu 10.04
After executing below command, i got errors related to glib-2.31.2.

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

I solved those errors and again issued above command. I got below errors.

```
checking for ZLIB... configure: error: Package requirements (zlib) were not met:

No package 'zlib' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ZLIB_CFLAGS
and ZLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing the development files for zlib (not glib). Would a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Install zlib on Linux web server

For ubuntu, or debian based distribution

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev zlib1g-dev
```